# PHP cron/scheduled task automatico

Tags: php, cron, schedule

El objetivo es que teniendo script.php, este se lance solo cada día como si fuera 0 0 * * * script.php.

Ha de ser agnosticamente debido a que puede ir alojado en diferentes mv ya sean windows/linux y sin depender de un container en el que podamos programar tareas.

Quizás existe alguna librería o de algún método con threads php...
Pero no lo he conseguido de momento, si alguno tiene alguna idea de como hacerlo sería de gran ayuda.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Posiblemente este enlace te de una luz para resolver esto https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428

Comment: Esto lo debes configurar en las cron tasks de tu servidor, que ejecuten este archivo con la versión php que necesite. Depende de si es centos, ubuntu,windows... lo tendrás que hacer de una manera u otra